# Keeping track of our statistics

Tags: discussion, statistics

**Aug 7, 2019: Now that Martial Arts SE is no longer a beta website its Area51 statistics are not updated anymore which means this post won't be updated either.**

---

We cannot see any history of this site's traffic statistics (only moderators can do that but they are not allowed to share the data) so in this post we can keep track of the public statistics listed on the [Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4470/martial-arts) of this site<sup>*</sup>. 
I'll copy and add those statistics every other week to the table below so we can see how things are progressing. If I forget to add them, please feel free to update it yourself.

There is also a Quantcast estimate of our site's traffic, with the mean number of visitors per month, a sparkline of weekly visitors for the last 6 months, and the highest and lowest weekly visitor count in those 6 months. The Quantcast widget is here:

[image: Quantcast statistics]

```
   
Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            Site is no longer Beta!
2019-08-02  2739   0.8   99%     243   21   15    6548     3.4      1565    43754   
2019-07-24  2730   0.8   99%     243   21   15    6515     3.4      1593    40437
2019-07-10  2716   0.9   99%     243   21   15    6493     3.4      1545    41176
2019-06-26  2702   0.9   99%     236   20   15    6469     3.4      1605    43826
2019-06-12  2688   0.5   99%     236   20   15    6450     3.4      1779    48190
2019-05-29  2674   0.4   99%     236   20   15    6426     3.4      1935    51127
2019-05-15  2660   0.4   99%     238   20   15    6385     3.4      1988    49853
2019-04-18  2633   0.7   99%     237   20   15    6353     3.4      2050    53311
2019-04-03  2618   0.6   99%     236   20   15    6334     3.4      2072    55025
2019-03-20  2604   0.3   99%     236   20   15    6308     3.4      2098    56508
2019-02-20  2576   0.8   99%     234   19   15    6265     3.4      2124    60340
2019-02-06  2562   0.5   99%     233   19   15    6239     3.4      2236    58779
2019-01-23  2548   0.4   99%     230   19   14    6181     3.4      2136    47509
2019-01-09  2534   0.3   99%     228   19   14    6158     3.4      1767    44981


Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-12-27  2521   0.3   99%     227   19   14    6136     3.4      1722    48004
2018-12-12  2506   0.5   99%     227   19   14    6107     3.4      1981    52018
2018-11-28  2492   1.0   99%     227   19   14    6070     3.4      1899    52671
2018-11-14  2478   0.4   99%     227   19   14    6041     3.4      1979    53355
2018-10-31  2464   0.2   99%     227   19   14    6013     3.4      2124    54558
2018-10-17  2450   0.9   99%     227   19   14    5982     3.4      2170    53304
2018-10-03  2436   0.4   99%     227   19   14    5939     3.4      2021    52047
2018-09-19  2422   0.4   99%     227   19   13    5907     3.4      2007    51563
2018-09-05  2408   0.3   99%     227   19   13    5872     3.4      1993    52261
2018-08-22  2394   0.3   99%     229   19   13    5850     3.4      2053    52382
2018-08-08  2380   0.6   99%     228   19   13    5822     3.4      1967    47414
2018-07-25  2366   0.3   99%     228   19   12    5790     3.4      1763    41843
2018-07-11  2352   0.6   99%     226   18   12    5763     3.4      1551    41338
2018-06-27  2338   0.9   99%     223   18   12    5742     3.4      N/A**   43404
2018-06-13  2324   1.0   99%     218   18   12    5700     3.4      N/A**   44252
2018-05-30  2310   0.8   99%     212   18   12    5665     3.4      N/A**   43747
2018-05-16  2296   0.6   99%     211   18   12    5643     3.5      N/A**   46102
2018-05-02  2282   0.7   99%     209   18   12    5609     3.5      N/A**   50668
2018-04-18  2268   0.8   99%     209   18   12    5585     3.5      N/A**   53317
2018-04-04  2254   0.4   99%     209   17   12    5549     3.5      2020    53586
2018-03-21  2240   0.3   99%     209   17   12    5516     3.5      2157    53055
2018-03-07  2119   0.4   99%     209   17   12    5493     3.5      2015    51020
2018-02-28  2119   0.5   99%     209   17   12    5480     3.5      1987    50123
2018-02-07  2198   0.4   99%     209   17   12    5427     3.5      1943    48647
2018-01-24  2184   0.8   99%     207   17   12    5397*    3.5      1928    45125
2018-01-10  2170   0.5   99%     207   17   12    5479     3.5      1705    42579

 * decline in total users is caused by deletion of 114 spam accounts 
   (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306180/)
** Because of a bug the visits/day statistic was not available 
   (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/164138) 

Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-12-28  2157   0.5   99%     207   17   12    5457     3.5      1676    45285
2017-12-13  2142   0.4   99%     205   17   12    5416     3.5      1926    49181
2017-11-29  2128   0.2   99%     205   17   12    5289     3.5      1893    48359
2017-11-15  2114   0.1   99%     202   17   12    5250     3.5      1961    48891
2017-11-01  2100   0.3   99%     202   17   12    5221     3.5      1904    49568
2017-10-18  2086   0.5   99%     199   17   12    5192     3.5      1934    51459
2017-10-04  2072   0.8   99%     198   17   12    5152     3.5      1999    60012
2017-09-20  2058   0.6   99%     200   17   12    5133     3.5      2527    67490
2017-09-06  2044   0.5   99%     199   17   12    5066     3.5      2738    63764
2017-08-23  2030   0.6   99%     199   17   12    5044     3.6      2250    58236
2017-08-09  2016   0.9   99%     198   17   12    5006     3.6      2318    59700
2017-07-27  2003   1.2   99%     196   17   12    4961     3.6      2363    58755
2017-07-12  1988   0.7   99%     194   17   12    4930     3.6      2193    57877
2017-06-28  1974   0.4   99%     193   17   12    4877     3.6      2215    56001
2017-06-14  1960   0.7   99%     191   17   12    4846     3.6      2160    54128
2017-05-31  1946   0.6   99%     189   17   12    4806     3.6      2093    55664
2017-05-17  1932   0.5   99%     189   17   12    4776     3.6      2299    58616
2017-05-03  1918   0.8   99%     188   17   12    4746     3.6      2248    57926
2017-04-19  1904   0.6   99%     188   17   11    4698     3.6      2203    58173
2017-04-05  1890   1.1   98%     188   17   11    4663     3.7      2353    59764
2017-03-22  1876   0.8   98%     184   17   11    4625     3.7      2249    58493
2017-03-08  1862   0.8   99%     182   16   11    4584     3.7      2334    57807
2017-02-22  1848   0.6   99%     181   16   11    4534     3.7      2246    54720
2017-02-08  1834   0.6   99%     180   16   11    4492     3.7      2019    51668
2017-01-25  1821   1.2   99%     179   16   11    4441     3.7      2064    48729
2017-01-11  1806   0.9   98%     178   16   11    4394     3.7      1868    43611 

Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-28  1792   0.4   99%     177   16   10    4362     3.7      1650    43742 
2016-12-14  1778   0.9   99%     176   16   10    4333     3.7      1843    45216 
2016-11-30  1764   0.2   99%     176   16   10    4299     3.7      1716    43366 
2016-11-16  1750   0.5   99%     176   16   10    4276     3.7      1747    42899 
2016-11-02  1736   0.4   99%     174   16   10    4241     3.7      1708    44126 
2016-10-19  1722   0.5   98%     174   16   10    4208     3.7      1771    45995 
2016-10-05  1708   0.4   98%     173   16   10    4170     3.7      1750    46706 
2016-09-21  1694   0.6   98%     173   16   10    4140     3.7      1851    48384 
2016-09-08  1681   1.3   98%     173   15   10    4106     3.7      1877    57525 
2016-08-24  1666   0.7   98%     171   15   10    4064     3.7      2222    60545 
2016-08-10  1652   0.4   98%     171   15   10    4003     3.7      1870    51145 
2016-07-30  1641   0.4   98%     170   15   10    3983     3.7      1690    43354  
2016-07-13  1624   0.2   98%     170   15   10    3947     3.7      1654    42208  
2016-06-29  1610   0.7   98%     167   15   10    3912     3.7      1625    41899  
2016-06-15  1596   0.6   98%     166   15   10    3887     3.7      1661    43586
2016-06-01  1582   0.6   99%     166   15   10    3847     3.7      1694    44379
2016-05-18  1568   0.3   99%     166   14   10    3807     3.7      1712    48421
2016-04-20  1540   1.0   99%     163   14   10    3737     3.7      1817    58538
2016-04-06  1526   0.4   99%     162   14   10    3674     3.7      1891    58160
2016-03-23  1512   1.4   99%     159   13   10    3609     3.7      1941    50339
2016-03-09  1498   1.1   98%     155   13    9    3531     3.7      1832    47474
2016-02-25  1485   1.6   98%     154   13    9    3484     3.7      1740    45197
2016-02-10  1456   1.0   99%     153   13    9    3438     3.7      1795    47617
2016-01-27  1456   0.7   98%     153   13    9    3390     3.7      1790    46677
2016-01-13  1442   0.6   99%     151   13    9    3337     3.7      1783    43761

Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-12-30  1428   0.3   99%     151   13    9    3307     3.7      1521    44769
2015-12-16  1414   0.9   99%     151   13    9    3266     3.7      1804    51430
2015-12-02  1400   1.0   99%     147   13    9    3211     3.7      1828    52055
2015-11-18  1386   1.1   99%     145   13    9    3151     3.7      1911    48798
2015-11-04  1372   0.4   99%     143   13    9    3105     3.7      1846    46594
2015-10-21  1358   0.4   99%     143   13    9    3057     3.7      1801    45910
2015-10-07  1344   0.5   99%     139   13    9    3033     3.7      1798    47325
2015-09-23  1330   0.4   98%     138   13    9    2998     3.7      1821    46910
2015-09-08  1315   0.7   99%     138   13    9    2961     3.7      1813    45751
2015-08-26  1302   0.6   99%     137   13    9    2915     3.7      1774    45272
2015-08-13  1289   1.2   99%     137   13    9    2875     3.7      1783    46694
2015-07-29  1274   0.5   99%     134   13    9    2825     3.7      1797    45417
2015-07-16  1261   0.6   99%     131   13    8    2784     3.7      1730    42833
2015-07-04  1250   0.6   99%     130   13    8    2765     3.7      1628    42638
2015-06-15  1230   0.7   99%     127   13    7    2720     3.7      1711    41969
2015-06-01  1216   0.9   98%     127   12    7    2668     3.7      1644    41453
2015-05-18  1202   0.5   99%     126   12    7    2637     3.7      1658    42118
2015-05-04  1188   0.2   99%     125   12    7    2605     3.7      1705    40685
2015-04-20  1174   0.9   98%     123   12    7    2590     3.7      1588    39892
2015-04-06  1160   0.5   98%     122   11    7    2539     3.7      1529    39995
2015-03-24  1147   0.6   98%     122    9    7    2510     3.7      1582    40610
2015-03-09  1132   0.9   98%     121   10    7    2480     3.7      1579    39062
2015-02-24  1119   0.6   98%     119    9    7    2439     3.7      1495    37905
2015-02-10  1105   0.8   98%     119    9    7    2404     3.8      1461    37108
2015-01-26  1090   0.3   98%     119    9    7    2365     3.8      1420    34372
2015-01-12  1076   0.3   98%     119    9    7    2333     3.7      1307    32346

Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-12-29  1062   0.9   98%     119    8    6    2301     3.8      1130    32829
2014-12-16  1049   0.9   98%     119    7    6    2270     3.7      1362    33767
2014-12-01  1034   0.8   98%     118    7    6    2214     3.7      1195    32474
2014-11-16  1020   0.6   98%     118    7    6    2173     3.8      1221    32799
2014-11-03  1006   0.6   98%     118    7    6    2131     3.7      1233    30710
2014-10-20   992   0.7   98%     115    7    6    2101     3.8      1223    28098
2014-10-06   978   0.4   98%     115    7    6    2073     3.8      1058    22447 
2014-09-22   964   0.4   99%     115    7    6    2041     3.8       718    18642
2014-09-08   950   0.5   98%     114    7    6    2020     3.8       712    19325
2014-08-25   936   0.6   99%     114    7    6    1993     3.8       730    19929
2014-08-11   922   0.4   98%     114    7    6    1968     3.8       738    20291
2014-07-28   908   1.0   98%     114    6    6    1938     3.8       796    19789
2014-07-14   894   0.8   98%     114    6    6    1906     3.8       706    18444
2014-06-30   880   0.6   98%     114    6    6    1873     3.8       693    18352
2014-06-15   865   0.8   98%     113    6    6    1853     3.8       649    18505
2014-06-03   853   0.8   98%     113    6    6    1841     3.8       609    20676  
2014-05-19   838   0.6   98%     113    6    6    1819     3.8       944    24265
2014-05-05   824   0.6   98%     113    6    6    1802     3.9       927    24251
2014-04-22   811   0.8   98%     112    6    6    1773     3.9       921    24374
2014-04-07   796   0.4   98%     109    6    6    1735     3.9       943    25246
2014-03-24   782   0.6   98%     107    6    6    1712     3.9      1050    26689
2014-03-10   768   0.8   98%     107    6    6    1685     3.9      1070    26763
2014-02-24   754   0.4   98%     107    6    6    1647     3.9      1063    26085
2014-02-10   740   0.9   98%     106    6    6    1590     3.9      1018    26132
2014-01-27   726   0.2   98%     104    6    6    1545     3.9      1034    24912
2014-01-13   712   0.6   98%     102    6    6    1512     3.8       913    22087

Date      Days in  Qs/    %      200+ 2k+  3k+    Total   Answer   Visits   Qntcst
            beta   day  answrd   Usrs Usrs Usrs   Users   Ratio     /day    p/mth
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-12-30   698   0.6   98%      99    6    6    1486     3.8       768    22661
2013-12-16   684   0.8   99%      97    6    6    1468     3.7       925    24772
2013-12-04   672   0.4   98%      96    6    6    1428     3.7       938    24644
2013-11-19   657   1.1   98%      95    6    6    1391     3.7       894    21544
2013-11-06   644   0.4   98%      94    6    6    1370     3.7       750    18914
2013-10-24   631   0.6   98%      92    6    6    1351     3.7       663    17747
2013-10-11   618   0.2   98%      86    6    6    1324     3.7       639    17633
2013-09-23   600   0.4   98%      84    6    6    1296     3.6       641    16783
                    Changed to an update frequency of 2 weeks
2013-09-10   587   0.4   98%      84    6    6    1278     3.6       613    15308
2013-09-04   581   0.3   97%      83    6    6    1267     3.7       557    15009
2013-08-26   572   0.3   98%      83    6    6    1255     3.7       520    14468
                    Quantcast introduced a new calculation method
2013-08-21   567   0.2   98%      83    6    6    1245     3.6       520    10940
2013-08-12   558   0.1   98%      81    6    6    1234     3.6       537    10680
2013-08-05   551   0.3   97%      81    6    6    1227     3.6       530    10346
2013-07-29   544   0.6   97%      81    6    6    1217     3.6       505    10065
2013-07-22   537   0.6   97%      79    6    6    1197     3.6       473     9947
2013-07-16   531   0.7   97%      79    6    5    1185     3.6       473     9891
2013-07-09   524   0.5   97%      78    7    5    1171     3.6       473     9858
2013-06-24   509   0.2   97%      77    6    5    1148     3.6       472     9480
2013-06-17   502   0.5   97%      77    6    5    1128     3.6       462     9187
2013-06-10   495   0.4   97%      77    6    5    1123     3.6       468     9222
2013-06-04   489   0.4   97%      76    6    5    1109     3.6       464     8974
2013-05-27   481   0.6   97%      76    6    5    1095     3.6       472     8407
2013-05-20   474   0.4   97%      76    6    5    1082     3.6       463     ?
2013-05-13   467   0.6   97%      76    6    5    1074     3.6       422     7495
2013-05-06   460   0.6   96%      76    6    5    1064     3.6       368     7236
2013-04-29   453   0.5   97%      75    6    5    1054     3.6       368     7368
2013-04-22   446   0.4   97%      75    6    5    1044     3.6       374     7605
2013-04-15   439   0.4   97%      75    6    5    1027     3.6       367     7900
```

The figure for questions per day is a rolling 2-week mean. The figure for visits per day is a rolling 2-week median.

I've recently added a 'Days in beta' column so we can see how we are doing compared to other beta sites that started earlier or later (e.g. [Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/99) and [Personal Productivity SE](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/2132))

<sup>*</sup><sub>I stole the idea of keeping track of statistics from user [EnergyNumbers](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/48/energynumbers) who started such a [meta post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/99) on the Sustainability SE website. EnergyNumbers got the idea from user [F'x](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2700/fx) over on [Academia.SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/283/96),</sub>.

Comment: Super!  Thank you for doing this.

Comment: Truthfully, while I like this SE, the figures seem to indicate that we're really not making much of a foothold here.

Comment: @SeanDuggan But does that really matter? Isn't it more important that you like to use and visit this site? As long as the number of visitors are not in steep decline I think it's ok.

Comment: @THelper:
I honestly don't know. I know that there are Stack Exchanges which have been eliminated (I believe they still have content, just no interactivity) from the site due to low traffic. It's the same principle as closing off wings of a mall where there are no open shops. It cuts down on maintenance and reduces the chances of squatters and roaming gangs.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I think shutting down sites only happens during private beta, or if a site is hardly active anymore. I know [poker was asked if they were ok with shutting down](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/q/134), but then a group of people protested and the site is still active.

Comment: Ah... I see now that, since we're no longer in Beta, we're not getting the same level of stats.

Comment: @SeanDuggan indeed. We could still keep track of the visits registered by Quantcast, but none of the other stats are available anymore. In any case I decided to stop updating this post.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party on this, but thank you for starting this.

As far as the shutting down, there was a change in policy on beta sites a while back [as shown by this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). As long as we have enough moderators to actively monitor and handle flags, etc., the site is in no real danger of being shut down.