# How do we get users to ask more questions?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The number of questions/week is now at an all-time low. It's [currently at 0.2 questions/day](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/316/88). This means that we only got 3 new questions in the last 2 weeks, despite the fact that the number of users is still (slowly) increasing.

I know there are other posts here on meta about [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) but those focus on getting more users. I agree that getting more users is important, but how do we get users to ask (more) questions?

**EDIT:** A comparison with other beta sites also shows that MA has a relatively small amount of questions

```
Martial arts    509 days in beta   1148 users   397 questions
Sports          501 days in beta   1370 users   788 questions
Sustainability  145 days in beta    620 users   351 questions
Tridion         124 days in beta   1151 users   602 questions
```

Comment: Challenge accepted

Answer (score 6):

One of the big things we can do is… ask more questions ourselves. If we could get a core group who would commit to one question a week, then that would be sufficient to significantly drive up our numbers and bring more users to the site.

Heck, even if people would commit to asking one question a month, that would be a significant improvement.

Another possibility is we can reevaluate our scope.  Is there anything we can tweak on the scope of the site that would be a good stepping stone to bring in more questions and more people?

Comment: Good idea. I think we'd better start with something like this soon. MA is almost at the [bottom of all sites when it comes to questions/day](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday)